# How to convert efficiently a dataframe column of string type into datetime in Python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a column with IDs and the time is encoded within. For example:

```
0    020160910223200_T1
1    020160910223200_T1
2    020160910223203_T1
3    020160910223203_T1
4    020160910223206_T1
5    020160910223206_T1
6    020160910223209_T1
7    020160910223209_T1
8    020160910223213_T1
9    020160910223213_T1
```

If we remove the first and the last three characters, we obtain for the first row: 20160910223200 which should be converted to 2016-09-10 22:32:00.

My solution was to write a function which truncates the IDs and transforms to a datetime. Then, I applied this function to my df column.

```
from datetime import datetime
def MeasureIDtoTime(MeasureID):
    MeasureID = str(MeasureID)
    MeasureID = MeasureID[1:14]
    Time = datetime.strptime(MeasureID, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return Time
df['Time'] = df['MeasureID'].apply(MeasureIDtoTime)
```

This works properly, however is slow for my case. I have to deal with more than 20 million rows, and I need a faster solution. Any idea for a more efficient solution?

**Update**

According to @MaxU there is a better solution:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.ID.str[1:-3], format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

This does the job in 32 seconds for 7.2 million rows. However, in R thanks to `lubridate::ymd_hms()` function, I performed the task in less then 2 seconds. So I am wondering if there exists a better solution for my problem in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** performance optimization...

Let's try to optimize it a little bit

DF shape: 50.000 x 1

```
In [220]: df.head()
Out[220]:
                   ID
0  020160910223200_T1
1  020160910223200_T1
2  020160910223203_T1
3  020160910223203_T1
4  020160910223206_T1

In [221]: df.shape
Out[221]: (50000, 1)

In [222]: len(df)
Out[222]: 50000
```

Timing:

```
In [223]: %timeit df['ID'].apply(MeasureIDtoTime)
1 loop, best of 3: 929 ms per loop

In [224]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df.ID.str[1:-3])
1 loop, best of 3: 5.68 s per loop

In [225]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df.ID.str[1:-3], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
1 loop, best of 3: 267 ms per loop    ### WINNER !
```

**Conclusion:** explicitly specifying the datetime format speeds it up 21 times.

NOTE: it's possible only if you have a constant datetime format

**OLD answer:**

```
In [81]: pd.to_datetime(df.ID.str[1:-3])
Out[81]:
0   2016-09-10 22:32:00
1   2016-09-10 22:32:00
2   2016-09-10 22:32:03
3   2016-09-10 22:32:03
4   2016-09-10 22:32:06
5   2016-09-10 22:32:06
6   2016-09-10 22:32:09
7   2016-09-10 22:32:09
8   2016-09-10 22:32:13
9   2016-09-10 22:32:13
Name: ID, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

where `df` is:

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
                   ID
0  020160910223200_T1
1  020160910223200_T1
2  020160910223203_T1
3  020160910223203_T1
4  020160910223206_T1
5  020160910223206_T1
6  020160910223209_T1
7  020160910223209_T1
8  020160910223213_T1
9  020160910223213_T1
```

Comment: I tried this method, and it's slower. For 50000 values needs 4.781 seconds, while my approach needs 0.737 seconds.

Comment: This is definitely a better solution. For 7.2 million rows took 32s, while my solution took 1 min 45s.